# Java file type passive in Syntastic for GVim

Tags: java, vim, syntastic

I'm currently trying to configure `Syntastic` for Java programming. I set my global mode to be 'active'. However, upon saving the checker is not running. I ran the `SyntasticInfo` command and was told that

> java filetype is passive

I read the documentation and edited my vimrc file as needed by adding on:

```
 let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
 "mode": "active",
 "active_filetypes": ["java"],
 "passive_filetypes": []}
```

However, when I tried saving my file after this change there is no difference. The checker is still not running when I save my file `SyntasticInfo` is still stating that

> java filetype is passive.

I was wondering how to change java to an active file type if the above method is not working.

Comment: Exit out of the Vim instance that is editing your `.java` file, then start Vim up with the same file and see if the changes have taken effect.

Comment: By any chance do you happen to have Eclim installed?

Comment: @MicahElliott I did that, and unfortunately java is still passive.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I do have Eclim installed.

Comment: Eclim helpfully disables syntastic checkers.  Recent versions of syntastic warn you when they detect that situation.  Read Eclim's manual to find out how to tell Eclim to re-enable syntastic checkers.